# yii cgridview update depending on dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, php, yii

I'm newbie with Yii.
I have a CGridview with a cutom dataprovider which takes a parameter `$select`:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id' => 'beneficiary-grid',
'dataProvider' => $model->searchForVoucherAssignment($select),
'filter' => $model,
'columns' => array(
            'id',
    'registration_code',
    'ar_name',
            'en_name',
            'family_member',
            'main_income_source',
            'combine_household',
            array( 'class'=>'CCheckBoxColumn', 'value'=>'$data->id', 'selectableRows'=> '2', 'header' => 'check', 
            ),
),
));
```

That parameter `$select` takes its values from `dropdownlist`:

```
$data = CHtml::listData(Distribution::model()->findAll(array("condition"=>"status_id =  2")), 'id', 'code');
$select = key($data);
echo CHtml::dropDownList(
    'distribution_id',
    $select,            // selected item from the $data
    $data,       
    array(
    )
);
```

So I defined a script to update the CGridview depending on the value of dropdownlist

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('sel_status', "
        $('#selStatus').change(function() {
            $.fn.yiiGridView.update('beneficiary-grid', {
                    data: $(this).serialize()
            });            
            return false;
        });
    ");
```

My model:

```
public function searchForVoucherAssignment ($distribution_id = 0) {
            $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
            if ($distribution_id != 0) {
                $criteria->condition = "Custom Query...!!";
            }
            $criteria->compare('id', $this->id);

            //Custom Criteria

             return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
                'criteria' => $criteria,
                'pagination' => array(
                                    'pageSize' => 20,
                                ),
            ));
        }
```

The problem is that the CGridview isn't changing where a value of the `dropdownlist` changed...

Comment: is an ajax request getting triggered on dropdown change?

Comment: yes but no change appeared

Comment: is the ajax response the correct data? if it is most likely you have some errors on your view i.e. the HTML page (could be missing tags, js errors etc) if it is not returning correct data then there is problem in your model/controller

Answer (score 1):

I think you have selected the wrong Id for the change event. The Id should be

```
$('#distribution_id').change(function() {
```